# How do I write the query to find all the customer names and their addressing whether they have an address or not?

Tags: sql

How do I write the query to find all the customer names and their addressing whether they have an address or not?

```
CREATE TABLE test.address
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  street text,
  city text,
  CONSTRAINT address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE TABLE test.customer
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name text,
  CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE TABLE test.customer_addresses
(
  id integer,
  customer_id integer,
  address_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT customer_addresses_address_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
    REFERENCES test.address (id),
  CONSTRAINT customer_addresses_customer_id_fkey FORE IGN KEY (customer_id)
    REFERENCES test.customer (id)
)
```

Comment: This is tagged MySQL and Oracle - they are different RDBMS - which one are you using?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please post a [MCVE] including some example data (DML statements), the expected output and, most importantly, what **YOU** have attempted to solve the problem and any errors **YOU** have encountered.

Comment: Hint: [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html)

Comment: Thanks MT0, I'm the new learner for SQL. .

Comment: SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  right join customer
  4  on test.id=customer.id;

 ID STREET       CITY          ID
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ----------
NAME
-------------------------
 10 street1       city1          10
hello

 12 street2       city2          12
hgang

         0
hiii

Comment: This is hard to read. You can add the query to your request telling us what your problem with the query is. Four points: 1. `from test`? You have mentioned no table called `test`. 2. Two tables in the query, but three mentioned. 3. `test.id=customer.id` So the test table is a customer table where the id is a customer id??? 4. RIGHT outer joins are uncommon and rather hard to read with more tables involved. Better use LEFT outer joins instead.